# How do I change my iPhone App binary filename

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I get the following error when I try to upload the application on iTunes Connect:

"Binary file names cannot contain a space. Please rename your binary file and try again."

If I try to Validate the Application in XCode, I get:
"My Application.ipa: filename may not contain whitespace"

So I guess I have to find a way to rename this .ipa file. I don't want to change my product name which has to stay "My Application". How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This works very well (taken from here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/82971/filename-may-not-contain-whitespace-in-xcode-325-is-back):

1) In Xcode Organizer right click on the build date of the app and select "Reveal Archived App in Finder"

2) Open ArchiveInfo.plist in a text editor (i used Coda)

3) For me at line 12 it was creating the application with a space:

```
  <key>XCApplicationName</key>
  <string>Example Name</string>
```

Change that to ExampleName and save the file.

4) Once you get back to Xcode Organizer, you should be able to go through fine.

Comment: This works with submitting through the Xcode organizer, that's why it's the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: I prefer doing the editing in Property List Editor - but otherwise agree that this is best way to remove spaces.

Comment: Changing the app name doesn't just change the ipa created it also actually changes how the App is displayed in the App store and on the iPhone. Removing the whitespace in my app name because of this bug isn't an option. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Following the steps as described above won't change the display name of the app, neither on the device nor in the App Store.

Comment: As soon as I change the value of XCApplicationName and save ArchiveInfo.plist, the target no longer exists in Organizer. Why is Apple doing this to us developers. I h*te it! There has to be another way to properly solve this issue!

Answer (score 6):

Since Xcode or the Application Loader is the only way to submit apps now, renaming the file before using the web interface isn't an option.

However, there is a workaround. From Xcode Organizer, choose Save to Disk, pick a file name without a space, and then use Application Loader (not the Xcode Organizer) to send the archive to Apple.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this and another issue when I wanted to submit an app with whitespace and a `+` in the name.

Application Loader did not work well for me - cryptic errors that required deleting the IPA and rebuilding.

My final solution was to set the `PRODUCT_NAME` to something sane, e.g. instead of `My App+` it was `MyAppPro`. Then I set `CFBundleDisplayName` in `Info.plist` to the name I wanted, e.g. `My App+`.

This is in my opinion a better solution than renaming the IPA every time and using Application Loader.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to rename the zip file before uploading it in the web interface. This is really silly...

Comment: This is not a option anymore since the the loader is the only way to upload now.

Comment: @valexa - So rename the .app before compressing and loading in the loader.

Answer (score 2):

Use Xcode 4.

The problem is solved in this version.

Comment: And reintroduced in 4.2... /o\

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to change anything in XCode. Just rename the resulting .zip File from "My Application.zip" to "**My_Application.zip**". This does not affect your application name its just a way to bypass the Application Loader filename checks (which do not allow whitespaces in the uploaded zip filename).

My_Application.zip should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the Organizer, select Share, Save to disk. The went to the file and told Finder to open it with Application Loader v1.4. This is with XCode 3.2.5. I've previously used Application Loader to upload apps to the Mac app store.