# iTunes Connect: How to change the bundle id prior to app submission?

Tags: iphone

We are getting ready to upload our app. At this point, itunes connect information has been entered. The problem is, we decided to change the name of our app from

ourAppMobile -> ourApp

The concern is that in iTunesConnect the Bundle ID is listed as: 
com.ourcompany.ourAppMobile

But, we have changed our app name to ourApp.

What to do? Can the Bundle ID be changed in iTunes Connect. If so, how? If not, what to do?

Thanks.

```
> Identifiers
> 
> SKUICC_MOBILEAPPLE Bundle ID
> com.ourcompany.ourAppMobile  Apple ID
> 395529813 Type iOS App
```

Comment: You might want to accept some answers to your earlier questions first.

Answer (score 6):

As you suspect there is no possibility to change the Bundle ID or better say App ID Suffix. Your only solution to make a new Bundle ID and upload the app with this ID. 
This Bundle ID is which make your app unique on the AppStore and follows it thorough all its lifespan and based on this iTunes recognize it from upgrade to upgrade.

The Bundle Display Name is totally different, and you can change as you like in line with Apple guidance. The APP ID prefix could be the same for various apps but it's again not the Bundle ID you are asking for.

Actually I don't really understand why do you bother with the internal name of the app as this will be unseen for the users. It's just a string nothing else, nobody use it or read it. The APP ID suffix could be anything even different from the Apple recommendation of com.companyname etc., and the only limitation that it has to be different from another APP ID, this is why it's unique and you couldn't change it any more.

Answer (score 1):

In your Info.plist for project add/modify value for CFBundleDisplayName (aka 'Bundle Display Name') to the desired app name. Then rebuild.

If your app name contains a space then you will need to take an extra step in the midst of validation process. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035081/how-do-i-change-my-iphone-app-binary-filename) out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not an XCode issue. It is an iTunes Connect issue. I asked if you could change a bundle id entered previously in the iTunes Connect portal. The answer is no but it doesn't really matter if you follow the rules in post 0.

Comment: Down votes should be accompanied by comment - how else are we to learn?

Comment: I would appreciate if you can edit your answer here. Coz its very misleading.

Comment: Apparently my answer from 4 years ago is misleading. Please treat as such. @Alix please elaborate on why it's misleading. Thanks.

Comment: @westsider : No offense but that guys is not asking about the bundle name. its bundle id. which is different that bundle ID. I am not where in compare to in those ios world. I would love to look up to you. that's a reason I wanted you revisit your answer. it might be 4 years old but as you can see. people are still look at it. coz things has not changed much in 4 years for us developers :)

Answer (score -1):

From another forum....

"You can either go ahead with the original bundle Id (these are always your choice as long as they are unique or wildcard for your account) or abandon that effort and start over with a new ID and upload using it. However, you will have to change the app name too..."

In my case, I did not want to change the app name in iTunes Connect or so I'm keeping the bundle id I originally entered as suggested.