# Error after binary is uploaded to iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios4, itunes, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I get the following message once the binary is uploaded.

> Your binary has been received but does not meet all the requirements for submission

What things could be wrong? It works fine on a device.

Comment: Please consider joining [the App Store proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred to the below link and followed the steps as mentioned by **Riceo**

[What can cause "invalid binary" with no email followup from iTunes Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433360/what-can-cause-invalid-binary-with-no-email-followup-from-itunes-connect)

It gave me following **Error** while validating in Organizer as my appname needed to contain whitespace

`My app.ipa filename may not contain whitespace`

Then I reffered to below link and followed the steps as mentioned by **Johannes Fahrenkrug**

[How do I change my iPhone App binary filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035081/how-do-i-change-my-iphone-app-binary-filename)

It finally worked and finally my app status changed to **Waiting For Review**

Hope this helps all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that your binary has the required artwork, icons and is signed properly. You should suit using the application loader. Using Xcode will work but won't tell you what your issue is.

You may have:

1. Signed with a development certificate instead of a distribution certificate
2. Not included the 512px square iTunes artwork
3. Not included default launch images
4. Not included icons
5. A space in your binary name. This may happen if your project name has a space in it. Just rename it in Finder.